# Django: Search products starting with query => product_name__starswith=query

Tags: python, django, django-models

Products model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Queryset

```
Products.objects.filter(product_name__startswith=query)
```

I want to find all the products starting with search `query` only.

For example: When I search for `ca` it returns

```
car
car cover
```

and when I search for `car cover`, it only returns

```
car cover
```

But I want it to return `car` in the second search as well. Is there any possible way to do it? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below, it may help:

```
Products.objects.filter(product_name__contains=query)
```

Here it will search whether "query" is there anywhere in the product_name.

Comment: OP needs a solution when query contains field value, not vice versa.

Comment: I want the result to start with the query value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by annotating your searched string literal with [`Value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) and using it with [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters):

```py
# `query` supposed given

products = Products.objects.annotate(
    query=Value(query, output_field=CharField())
).filter(
    query=F("product_name")
).all()
```